# What does the [whatever]:[number] construct mean in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, devtools

When I was using the developer console in the browser, I accidentally entered a construction like `whatewer:42`
The console in response output a number after the colon. I don't understand why such a construction is needed. If you use it anywhere else, you get an error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you use it anywhere else, you get an error.

No, you don't. It's a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

```js
function test() {
  whatever: 42;
  console.log('No error');
}

test();
```